# Update of quantity is modifying Sales Price but not Total Price

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, product

Can anyone help me out in understanding the below functionality.

When i am trying to change Quantity on OopportunityLineItem, SalesPrice is getting change but not the Total Price.

For Ex -

```
Sales Price - 500
Quantity - 10.00
Total Price - 5000
```

Now i will update `Quantity to 11.00`

```
Quantity - 11.00
Sales price - 454.55
Total Price - 5000.05
```

Is this the standard scenario.

Regards

Comment: can you post attributes of that product

Comment: Hi Santanu..Sorry , I didnt get it.. Attribute means?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of your use case scenario. Definitely Schedule has been defined at Opportunity Line Item level. That's why there is no change in Total Price and Sales Price is getting adjusted based on Quantity.

> This line item has Sales Price $12,000 and Quantity is 3, so Total Price = $36,000

[image: pic1]

> Now, create a schedule based on Quantity.

[image: Pic2]

> Then, edit the quantity from 3 to 4 as follows:

[image: Pic3]

> You see that Total Price remains same ($36000) but Sales Price has been adjusted to $9000.

[image: Pic4]

Comment: Hello @santanu. I am facing the same issue in my org and I checked that opportunity product schedule are not enabled. Can you suggest any other case when such issue occurs?

Answer (score 0):

[Update of quantity is modifying Sales Price but not Total Price](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/241404/update-of-quantity-is-modifying-sales-price-but-not-total-price)

When you update Quantity the unit price is updated so that the TotalPrice does not change.

In my opinion this is very counterintuitive.

Answer (score 0):

create custom field new sales price and also create total Price field

both will be the formula field

custom sales price = Quantity * UnitPrice(standard)

custom Total price = Quantity *  Custom sales Price

change the layout and replace old fields with new

Comment: formula return type will be number

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple answer just remove sales price from compact layout and add sales price field in pagelayout the check sales price will not adjust.

steps :

1. go to page layout of opportunity product
2. drag sales price field to the object layout
3. save

if sales price not on the pagelayout it will changed when you make changes in quantity

test the steps change quantity sales price will not changed

hope it will work I have tested you can try it .